# wp7 app working fine posting to wall, however, the app link that is included automatically is a bad link?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

The link added to all posts by the windows phone 7 application is:
http://www.facebook.com/#!/apps/application.php?id=341481639238665

Where can I adjust this link?  I tried in the facebook app settings but did not see a place to adjust the URL/URI.

Here is an example:
nigel wuz here from my custom free t.v. windows phone app

Like · · Share · 3 minutes ago via Free T.V. Windows Phone ·

The link added for this line: Free T.V. Windows Phone   directs to a page that does not exist, where can I customize this?

The page you requested was not found..

You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive.
■
Return home

■
Go back to the previous page

I have all the hard part working just need to adjust this part which should be fairly easy as some sort of set up option?

Thanks for any help you can offer, it is much appreciated, and may also help others with Windows Phone and Facebook integrations...

Answer (score 0):

This link isn't really part of published story but a link that Facebook provide to your application (once updated it'll be corrected for every old stories too).

Actual URL for that link may be different according to application settings like:

- Page URL
- Canvas URL
- Site URL

See my [more detailed answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/10469716/155033) to similar question: [Facebook apps redirecting “via {APP_NAME}” to an existing pages](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/10467644/155033)